# Are category of perfect groups and acyclic space equivalent?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Here is my approach to relate two subcategories of $\textbf{hTop}$ and $\textbf{Gp}$ respectively:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the full subcategory of $\textbf{hToP}$ consisting of acyclic( i.e. reduced homology in all degree is zero ) CW complex and $\mathcal{D}$ denote the category of perfect groups (i.e. commutator is itself). There is functor $\mathcal{F} = \pi_{1} : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ takes space $X$ to its fundamental group $\pi_{1}(X)$. We have also another functor $\mathcal{G} : \mathcal{D} \rightarrow 
\mathcal{C}$ given as if $P$ is any perfect group then define $\mathcal{G}$(P) to be the homotopy fiber of the plus construction map $ BP \rightarrow BP^{+}$. The above two functors seems too natural to me. So  mine natural questions are the following:

1. Are $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ equivalent categories?
2. Is $\mathcal{F}$ related to $\mathcal{G}$  (I mean whether they are in adjunction, equivalence pair etc.)?

I computed the composition $\mathcal{FoG}$:  Let $P$ be a perfect group and $F(f)$ denote the homotopy fiber of $ BP \rightarrow BP^{+}$. Then $\mathcal{FoG}(P) = \pi_{1}(F(f))$ and the counit map $\mathcal{FoG}(P) = \pi_{1}(F(f)) \rightarrow P $ is the universal central extension map which in particular says that if we again repeat the same process turns out to be identity. So this is in a way saying that $\mathcal{FoG}$ may not be identity but its square is identity. I don't know what it means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can deduce that the answer to 1 is negative by using [Dror, Emmanuel. “Acyclic Spaces.” Topology 11, no. 4 (December 1, 1972): 339–48. https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(72)90030-4.] actually, constructing a wide range of explicit examples of why this fails. IMHO your heuristics would be very similar to thinking that the homotopy category of pointed spaces (connected CW-complexes) were equivalent to the category of groups via the fundamental group.

Comment: A suitable localization of the category of groups gives an equivalence between the category of perfect groups and the homotopy category of simply connected spaces. The equivalence is given by the quillen plus construction

Comment: For more details, take a look to Kan-Thurston article and Baumslag article.